# Understanding glTexCoord2f(), glVertex3f() in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, oculus

I'm trying to build in OculusRift support into our car simulator software at our institute. Due to the way the simulator software is setup we decided to fix the distortion due to the lenses client side build a display list with OpenGL to run the first tests.

Basically where I'm struggly a bit is understanding how OpenGL does the drawing (for the display list). I used the info from different tutorials and if I understand it correctly the following for-loop would select the coordinates for Tex 0,1,2 do some vignetting and bind it to each vetice. The `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` would automatically draw triangles out of the vertices.

The coordinates of the vertices are stored in a struct the address `ov` is pointing to. Additionally we have offsets for each color channel.

Is the following code snipped from a OpenGL viewpoint correct?

```
ovrHmd_CreateDistortionMesh(pHmd, eyeRenderDesc[eyeNum].Eye, eyeRenderDesc[eyeNum].Fov,
ovrDistortionCap_Chromatic | ovrDistortionCap_Vignette, &meshData);

ovrDistortionVertex * ov = meshData.pVertexData;

// New compiled distortion-rendering display list
glNewList(drList, GL_COMPILE);

// Make triangles out of the vertices
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

for (unsigned int vertNum = 0; vertNum < meshData.VertexCount; vertNum++) {
    // Tex0,1,2 have already been activated
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, ov->TanEyeAnglesR.x, ov->TanEyeAnglesR.y);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, ov->TanEyeAnglesG.x, ov->TanEyeAnglesG.y);
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, ov->TanEyeAnglesB.x, ov->TanEyeAnglesB.y);
    glColor4f(
    (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
    (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
    (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
    (OVR::UByte)(ov->TimeWarpFactor * 255.99f));
    glVertex3f(ov->ScreenPosNDC.x, ov->ScreenPosNDC.y, 0.5); // z: constant
    ov++;
}

glEnd();
glEndList();
```

Comment: display lists and the glBegin/glEnd are deprecated. Instead create VBOs and use shaders

Comment: Even though they are deprecated, they should still work (and I do tend to use them out of sheer laziness :) ). Your code looks OK, can you tell us what doesn't work?

Comment: @ratchetfreak The software itself is mainly used to develop car control systems and has the option to let you drive the car.  What happens is that the software is written in a TCL scripting language with c/c++ extension and I can't just rewrite the complete rendering process.
The OVR support will be experimental (without timewarp) and will be done by calls to a DLL working as a TCL wrapper for the OculusSDK. Hence the display list use.

Comment: @martin_pr since I'm new to OpenGL I just wanted to know if I did understand correctly the way glTexCoord glColor and glVertex have to be used, call-order-wise. And from what you have commented it looks ok this way ;)

Comment: Yup, glTexCoord and glColor is to be called before glVertex. These functions are a bit ancient, though, and the comments on the answer below do have a point :)

Comment: @Skaveelicious: Yes that is all correct, `glVertex` effectively finalizes vertices taking the *last* attributes you specified using `glColor`, `glTexCoord`, `glNormal`, etc. and associating them with a new vertex. You actually don't have to call anything but `glVertex` per-vertex, because the old values for all of those states will be used if you don't change them. So, say you had a per-triangle color instead of per-vertex, you could move `glColor4f` out of that loop.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you fo the input. You helped me a lot getting a clearer picture. @AndonM.Coleman I did not know that it worked that way, many thanks there aswell.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing the distortion rendering yourself instead of letting the SDK do the distortion?  The SDK is typically going to use the fastest possible code for distortion, and the code should only get better as new SDKs arrive.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to build in OculusRift support into our car simulator software at our institute. Due to the way the simulator software is setup we decided to fix the distortion due to the lenses client side build a display list with OpenGL to run the first tests.

**Stop right there!** You're targeting a VR display, which means you must use the highest performance drawing method you can get to draw dynamic meshes (required for the timewarping). Display Lists can't do this. Actually the immediate mode (`glBegin` … `glEnd`) creates lots of CPU overhead which is exactly what you don't want to have.

Comment: I'm developing this as my thesis for experimental use (see my comment above for more info). The guy that developed the software and is helping me told me that I could achieve some first experimental results without timewarp (use a constant) and for that it's enough to use a "one-time" created display list.

Comment: @Skaveelicious: Even if that's the case, you're iterating over the vertices of some mesh data structure there. It's far easier to just coax the mesh data into a OpenGL vertex array and do a single `glDrawArrays` call, than to manually iterate over the darn thing.

Comment: Actually it's easier to simply let the SDK do the distortion rendering, or if that's not possible for some reason, pull the OpenGL code to distortion directly out of the Oculus SDK (which is public source)

Comment: Jherico, nice to see you here.I'm doing a sort of academic experimental (no timewarp) solution for an existing software. The guy that knows the software "in-and-out" told me that the best thing is to hand him the distortionMesh as a display list. He will be calling my function that has been loaded as a DLL into the TCL scripting language from within his rendering loop and grab the display list Id. I tried what you said but the heavy class usage in the SDK made me get lost. Additionally I have been told that they are still using OGL 2.x so I wanted to keep things simple =/

Comment: You shouldn't be looking into the SDK implementation.  Everything you need to do SDK based distortion is available in the OVR_CAPI.h header (which is pure C), using `configureRendering()`, `beginFrame()` and `endFrame()`

Answer (score 0):

```
glColor4f(
  (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
  (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
  (OVR::UByte)(ov->VignetteFactor * 255.99f),
  (OVR::UByte)(ov->TimeWarpFactor * 255.99f));
```

`glColor4f` expects floating point values clamped between 0 and 1.  However, you are passing it bytes.  Perhaps you're confusing it with `glColor4b`?

Comment: Yes a mitake of mine. I'm learning something new each day and did oversee that. There are many other things that are wrong, like the Texture Coords, they have to be converted first and I have to iterate over the Indices and not the Vertices, in my approach. I'm in the process of rewriting my code to use element arrays instead, which would make it easier to pull the data from the meshData struct.